# I have problems in Prolog (Semantic Network Querying)

Tags: prolog, subclass

I am making a program in prolog and I want it to work this way:

I have these sentences defined:

```
isa(dumbo, smallelephant).

subclass(t1, tip).
subclass(t2, tip).
subclass(h1, head).
subclass(smallelephant, elephant).
subclass(elephant, animal).

partOf(head, animal).
partOf(tip, animal).
partOf(t1, smallelephant).
partOf(t2, elephant).
partOf(h1, elephant).


%property definitions
subclass(C, S) :- isa(C, S).
subclass(C, S) :- subclass(C, X), subclass(X, S).


hasPart(Object, Part) :- partOf(Part, Object).

hasPart(Object, Part) :- subclass(Object, Class), hasPart(Class, Part).
```

With these sentences, for example, if I put this: `hasPart(dumbo, X).`
I get these results:

```
?- hasPart(dumbo, X).
X = t1;
X = t2;
X = h1;
X = head;
X = tip;
```

But what I want to do is: I don't want to get the superclasses of the parts of Dumbo. I mean, if, for example, I want to get `hasPart(dumbo, X)`, I want `X` to be: `t1`, `t2` and `h1`, but I don't want to get `head` and `tip`, because `t1` and `t2` are subclasses of tip, and `h1` is subclass of `head`.

I don't know how to do that, and it would be so helpful for me someone to say me how to do it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: As a point of terminology, what you have are not *sentences*. They are *facts* and *rules* (predicates). I think your problem is that your `subclass(Object, Class)` call in `hasPart/2` is backwards. You have defined `subclass(A, B)` in the facts to mean that `A` is a subclass of `B`, but you're calling it as if it means `B` is a subclass of `A`. So make your call, `subclass(Class, Object)` inside of `hasPart(Object, Part)`.

Comment: Not really. If I put subclass(A, B) I am saying that A isa subclass of B.

Comment: Right. But your predicate is acting otherwise. `hasPart(Object, Part) :- subclass(Object, Class), hasPart(Class, Part).` says that *`Object` has `Part` if `Object` is a subclass of `Class` and `Class` has `Part`* which is exactly contributing to the problem you are saying you have of displaying the parts of the super class. You want your `hasPart(Object, Part)` to yield `Part` of `Class` if `Class` is a *subclass* of `Object`, not a *super class*. Your logic in `hasPart/2` is backwards.

Comment: Exactly. In the way I have implemented the problem I get all the parts of all the elements, but I want not to get t1, t2, h1, head and tip. I want to get only t1, t2 and h1. So the question is: changing the hasPart(Object,Part) fact to hasPart(Object, Part) :- subclass(Object, Class), hasPart(Class, Part). the problem will be solved?

Comment: what I want to represent is: 'Object' has 'Part' if 'Object' is subclass of 'Class', and 'Class has 'Part', and there is not a part which is subclass of 'Part'. I put this fact: tieneParte(Object, Part) :- subclass(Object, Class), tieneParte(Class, Part), not(subclass(_,Part)).
But I didn´t solve the problem...What could I do to get

Comment: I see what you mean.... I was misunderstanding your `subclass` expression. It is the issue that it's reaching up to the super class and finding parts there, but just replacing it with the reverse is not the solution in this case.

Comment: I think you need to define succinctly what the rule is. When you want to check parts of superclasses of the object, how far up do you want to go? In your example, you're wanting to go 2 levels (one to get past the `isa` and then one more). Is it always limit 2? Or do you have some other categorization for higher level classes which needs to be defined? Also, you predicate has termination issues: it goes into a stack overflow after finding the solutions. Check your circular definition for `subclass`. It's typically a good idea to make the predicate name different than the fact to help separate.

Comment: Not the best title "I have problems in Prolog". I guess your problems relates to semantic network querying.